# Call a function, with array parameter

Tags: emscripten

`Module.cwrap(funcname, return, params)` is `Module.cwrap('square', 'number', ['number'])` if the C++ function looks like this: `int square(int);`

But what if my C++ function look like this? `int fnc(int, int[]);`

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first of while you can compile with C++, you have to export the function via C conventions (to prevent name mangling).

And then (as you probably know) `int[]` is nothing else than `int*` for C/C++.
So it again is a number:

```
Module.cwrap('fnc', ['number', 'number'], ['number'])
```